# Stuck on nested if statement challenge

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

[Nested If Statement Challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17l63.png)

[Copy of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZi8l.png)

Any guidance on this would be appreciated!

I tried to create a nested if statement so that the first and second if statement would be tested for truth and if it is true, then the statement "Both statements are true" is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print "Program ended." no matter what the four numbers were. Currently, you have that line in an else block, so it only prints if num1 >= num2 evaluated to false. Remember that an if statement doesn't always need a corresponding else statement.

Also, the else if statement can be replaced with an else statement. I would encourage you to think about why that is. Hint: what already had to be true for the program to reach the else if?